# Adding custom ssh key to vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I am testing provisioning with ansible locally and using vagrant I am simulate external machine. How to add my own key to vagrant and root user into vagrant box?

Comment: Do you want to get your keys into your box through ansible (like 
DomaNitro described below) or do you want to get those keys in there "manually" or by shell provisining so you are able to test your ansible setup?

Answer (score 2):

In your vagrant file you can use something like

```
  ## Ansible Provisioning
  cfg.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "vagrant-provision.yml"
      ## Debugging
      ansible.verbose =  true
      ansible.verbose="vvvvv"
  end
```

Create file called *vagrant-provision.yml* in the same dir as your vagrant file. I am assuming your using ubuntu you might want to amend the groups for other systems

```
---
#
# This playbook deploys your keys to the vagrant
#

- name: Provision my keys
  hosts: all
  sudo: True
  vars:
    localuser: "{{ lookup('ENV','USER') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Create your local user
      user: 
        name="{{localuser}}"
        home="/home/{{localuser}}"
        shell="/bin/bash"
        append="true"
        group="admin"
        comment="{{localuser}}"


    - name: Putting you authorized_key
      authorized_key: 
        key="{{lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')}}"
        user="{{localuser}}"
        manage_dir=yes
```

So in that case when the vagrant comes up it will use the the above code to deploy your keys

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by mixing **"file"** and **"shell"** provisining, eg:

```
$enable_root_passwordless_ssh_access = <<SCRIPT
#vagrant user has sudo passwordless access on precise32.box
[ -d /root ]      || sudo mkdir /root
[ -d /root/.ssh ] || sudo mkdir /root/.ssh
[ -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub ] && sudo mv /tmp/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
sudo chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
SCRIPT

machine.vm.provision "file",  source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", destination: "/tmp/id_rsa.pub"
machine.vm.provision "shell", inline: $enable_root_passwordless_ssh_access
```

Comment: @JonathanLeaders There is a typo in code above: script checks for `/root/.shh` instead of `.ssh`. Anyway the better implementation would be to use `mkdir -p /root/.ssh` - one command instead of four, see `man mkdir` for explanation.